# javafx dynamically add tooltip to each col

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tooltip

i have created a simple Tableview that should store notes,everything working fine but i want to add a tooltip to each column.
[Example of my TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsGwn.png)

As you can see the date wont fit in the cell, i want to add a tooltip there, if you hover over the cell with the mouse it should appear and show the entire string.
Basically the last 3 (date,noteTitle,noteTags) cells in each row should have an tooltip because they can overflow.

### Snipped out of the GUI-Class(creating the tableview)

```
        //create TableCols
        TableColumn colorCol = new TableColumn<Rectangle, String>("C");
        colorCol.setMinWidth(30.0);
        colorCol.setMaxWidth(30.0);
        TableColumn prioCol = new TableColumn<Note, String>("priority");
        prioCol.setMinWidth(70.0);
        prioCol.setMaxWidth(70.0);
        TableColumn dateCol = new TableColumn<Note, String>("date");
        dateCol.setMinWidth(150.0);
        dateCol.setMaxWidth(150.0);
        TableColumn titleCol = new TableColumn<Note, String>("title");
        titleCol.setMaxWidth(150.0);
        titleCol.setMinWidth(150.0);
        TableColumn tagsCol = new TableColumn<Note, String>("tags");
        tagsCol.setMaxWidth(100.0);
        tagsCol.setMinWidth(100.0);
        fxListView.getColumns().addAll(colorCol, prioCol, dateCol, titleCol, tagsCol); //add cols to table. fxListView is the table

        colorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rect"));
        prioCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priority"));
        dateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
        titleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("title"));
        tagsCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tags"));
        DBManager temp = new DBManager(); 
        fxListView.setItems(temp.getTableData()); // this Method just returns a ObservableList<Note> with a few test datas.
```

### Note-Class

```
  public class Note {
        private Rectangle rect;
        private String rectColorString;
        private String priority;
        private String date;
        private String title;
        private String note;
        private String tags;
        private String fontStyle;
        private int fontSize;

        public Note(String rectColorString, String priority,String title, String note,String tags, String fontStyle, int fontSize) {
            this.rectColorString = rectColorString;
            rect = new Rectangle(24, 24, Color.web(rectColorString));
            this.priority = priority;
            this.date =  new Date().toString();
            this.title = title;
            this.note = note;
            this.tags = tags;
            this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
            this.fontSize = fontSize;
        }
        public String getDate() {
            return this.date;
        }
        public Rectangle getRect() {
            return rect;
        }

        public void setRect(Rectangle rect) {
            this.rect = rect;
        }

        public String getRectColorString() {
            return rectColorString;
        }

        public void setRectColorString(String rectColorString) {
            this.rectColorString = rectColorString;
            this.rect = new Rectangle(24, 24, Color.web(rectColorString));
        }

        public String getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }

        public void setPriority(String priority) {
            this.priority = priority;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getNote() {
            return note;
        }

        public void setNote(String note) {
            this.note = note;
        }

        public String getTags() {
            return tags;
        }

        public void setTags(String tags) {
            this.tags = tags;
        }

        public String getFontStyle() {
            return fontStyle;
        }

        public void setFontStyle(String fontStyle) {
            this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
        }

        public int getFontSize() {
            return fontSize;
        }

        public void setFontSize(int fontSize) {
            this.fontSize = fontSize;
        }
    }
```

Heres also another picture on how i want the tooltips to appear(in case my explanation is not clear enough)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmTfD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this by using a custom `TableCell` implementation. Return such a implementation from the `cellFactory` of the columns:

```
public class TooltipTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    private final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
    private final Text measureText = new Text();
    private Node textDisplay;
    private final InvalidationListener listener = o -> {
        setTooltip((measureText.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > textDisplay.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()) ? tooltip : null);
    };

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        measureText.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(listener);
        Node oldTextDisplay = textDisplay;
        textDisplay = lookup("LabeledText"); // lookup node displaying the text via CSS

        if (oldTextDisplay != textDisplay) {
            if (oldTextDisplay != null) {
                oldTextDisplay.boundsInLocalProperty().removeListener(listener);
            }
            textDisplay.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(listener);
            listener.invalidated(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        String newText = empty || item == null ? "" : item.toString();
        setText(newText);
        tooltip.setText(newText);
        measureText.setText(newText);
    }

    public static <E, F> Callback<TableColumn<E, F>, TableCell<E, F>> forTableColumn() {
        return column -> new TooltipTableCell<>();
    }

}
```

```
titleCol.setCellFactory(TooltipTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

Note that it makes little sense to specify the type parameters on a constructor, but not at the declaration of the variable. Better specify it in the declaration and use the diamond operator in the constructor call:

```
TableColumn<Note, String> dateCol = new TableColumn<>("date");
```

(This will result in a compile time error for `colorCol`, if the declaration of `fxListView` contains a type parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Tooltip` to the cell rather than the `TableColumn`.

```
public class CustomTableCell extends TableCell<Note, String>() {

    private final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();

    public CustomTableCell() {
        tooltip.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean emtpy) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setTooltip(null); // so an empty cell doesn't display a Tooltip
        } else {
            setText(item);
            setTooltip(tooltip);
        }
    }
}
```

Then set the cell factory on your `TableColumn` using `column.setCellFactory(Callback)`.

**Edit:**

The [answer given by fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736880/6395627) also takes into account whether or not the entire item is already displaying before adding a `Tooltip`.